# The code passed is incorrect or expired in passport

Tags: javascript, express

I keep getting

> The code passed is incorrect or expired.
>
> GET /api/users/auth/github/callback?code=afefcf8b12561c910798 - - ms -
>   - [0] undefined [0] TokenError: The code passed is incorrect or expired. [0]     at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse
>   (/Users/eli/nodework/sequelize-demo/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:329:12)
>   [0]     at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError
>   (/Users/eli/nodework/sequelize-demo/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:376:16)

I think i have passport-github 0auth set up correctly.

I reseted all the tokens, and i still get the error.

**config/passport-config.js**

```
const GitHubStrategy = require('passport-github').Strategy;
const models = require( '../models/index');
require('dotenv').config();


module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  // from the user id, figure out who the user is...
  passport.deserializeUser(function(userId, done){
    models.User
      .find({ where: { id: userId } })
      .then(function(user){
        done(null, user);
      }).catch(function(err){
        done(err, null);
      });
  });


  passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
      clientID: process.env.clientID,
      clientSecret: process.env.secret,
      // if the callback is set to 5000 the 0auth app will not work for some reason
      callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users/auth/github/callback'

    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      models.User.findOne({ where: {'id': profile.id } }, 

      function (err, user) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);  // handle errors!
        }
        if (!err && user !== null) {
          done(null, user);
        } else {
          models.User.create({
            id: profile.id,
            username: profile.displayName,
            createdAt: Date.now()

          }).then(user => {
            console.log( refreshToken );
            console.log('user created');
            return done(null, user);
          });

        }
      });
    }
  ));
};
```

**routes/users.js**

```
router.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github') );

router.get('/auth/github/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/dashboard');

    console.log('this works');
});
```

Comment: Post complete code - your route handlers for `auth/github/callback` and `auth/github`

Comment: ok i updated now.

Comment: Hm nothing unusual there. FYI "code" is something oauth flow passes back in a param to your callback route and then you are supposed to make a request with it to get the accessToken etc. Strange that it says you're passing an incorrect one. You could start by adding a console log here in your node_modules and ensuring it is at least receiving a code - https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L73

Comment: yeahhhh, how would i utilize the accessToken ?

Comment: i fixed it. I sorta just copied from another github using passport 0auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credited by this repo

https://github.com/vittau/todoapp/blob/master/server.js

**config/passport-github.js**

```
  passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({
      clientID: process.env.clientID,
      clientSecret: process.env.secret,
      // if the callback is set to 5000 the 0auth app will not work for some reason
      callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/users/auth/github/callback'

    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {

      models.User
      .findOrCreate({where: {id: profile.id}, defaults: {username: profile.displayName}})
      .spread(function(user, created) {
        cb(null, user)
      });
```

router.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github',  { session: false, scope: ['profile'] }) );

```
router.get('/auth/github/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:3000/dashboard');

    console.log('this works');
});
```